# Where's did this div element come from?

Tags: customization

This div element is causing a big gap on my wordpress page, specifically on the single post page. It's nowhere in the themes, I can't seem to find where this div element is coming from. Have you encountered this before (the highlighted element)?
[image]

**PS**: Happens on chrome only.
**UPDATE:** Still having this problem even with the stable chrome. Help anybody?

**UPDATE2**: I think its the syntax highlighter plugin. And I also found out all other wordpress blogs (that I've checked) have this div. And the code's height in the post adds to the height of the div.

Comment: The image is a little difficult to read. Can you add just the source of that DIV html to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like JavaScript for your lightbox.

- edit

If this only happens in Chrome, there is a rendering bug that has gone unfixed for quite some time.

Add height:100%;  to the body or html element in your css.

Comment: deactivated lightbox, and still the same problem.

Comment: Is this only showing up in chrome? NM I saw you edit above, I added to me answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, your lightbox plugin generated it

Comment: I deactivated lightbox and its still there.

Comment: I would deactivate all plugins and see if one is causing it. Otherwise check your footer.php file and also your footer widgets.

Comment: @user1613 I think its the syntax highlighter plugin. And I also found out all other wordpress blogs (that I've checked) have this div. And the code's height in the post adds to the height of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with lightbox or shadowbox. Set the div css to display: inline. That's a chrome-specific stylesheet element.